# PHP: is empty($var) equivalent to !$var

Tags: php

For validating a variable value we can do

```
if(empty($var)){
}
```

OR

This will return true on empty string, 0 as number, false, null

```
if(!$var){
}
```

What is the difference between this two approaches, are them equivalent?

**EDIT**: Some examples where they behave different will be more pratical.

**EDIT2**: The only difference founded from answers is that the second will throw a notice if $var is undefined. What about the boolean value they return?

**EDIT3**: for $var I mean any variable with any value, or even an undefined variable.

**Conclusion from users answers**:
`if(!$var)` and `empty($var)` are equivalent as described here http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php, they will return the same bool value on the same variable.

`if(!$var)` will return a php notice if `$var` is not defined, normally this is not the case (if we write good code) most IDEs will underline it.

- When checking simple variables `if(!$var)` should be ok
- When checking arrays index ($var['key']) or object properties ($var->key) 
  `empty($var['key'])` is better using empty.

Comment: @James the problem is that since !$vars is shorter than empty($vars) many of us will prefer the first way, but the problem is are they equivalent always?

Comment: most of answers recall the documentation (a little ambiguous), practical example will be best to show in which values they behave different

Comment: For your second edit, [see my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27166812/php-is-emptyvar-equivalent-to-var#comment42826881_27167256).

Comment: @James Ok I understand what you mean, but I just ask here to have a better idea, from the experience of other developers and maybe things that you do not find in the php doc, example  $mysqli->multi_query will not run the queries if you do not flush them and this thing is not written in php docs.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath you mean your helpful comment  right? because mine was just sarcasm not insulting, inviting you to give an answer

Comment: Yes, that was actually useful. I can't help if you don't get it. and I already posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a boolean value return empty is equivaliend to !:

```
empty($var) === !$var; // supposed that $vars has been defined here
```

From a notice/waning notification they are not equivalent:

```
empty($array['somekey']); //will be silent if somekey does not exists
!$array['somekey']; // will through a warning if somekey does not exists
```

Answer (score 6):

> the problem is that since !$vars is shorter than empty($vars) many of us will prefer the first way

You prefer the first one because it is a "shorter way"?
Shorter code does not mean better code, or faster scripts ;)

The speed of PHP functions and its various other behaviours is not determined by the length of the function name. It is determined by what PHP is actually doing to evaluate, action, and return results.

Besides that, don't choose methods based on length of code, choose methods based on scenario and best approach "*for a given scenario*".
Which is best depends on what you need, and there are other variable checks other than the two you mentioned (`isset()` for one).

> but the problem is are they equivalent always

Not necessarily - see 
http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Or create a quick test script to see what PHP returns for your two scenarios.

You could also be initialising your variables in your framework (or, likely, stand alone script), which means the scenario changes, as could your question and approach you use.

It's all contextual as to which is the best.

### As for the required answer.

Anyway, to answer your question, here are some tests:

**`(!$vars)`**

Example code:

```
if ( !$vars )
 {
  echo "TRUE";
 }
else
 {
  echo "FALSE";
 }
```

will return:
Notice: Undefined variable: vars in /whatever/ on line X
TRUE

However, if you initialise the var in your scripts somewhere first:

```
$vars = "";
$vars = NULL;
$vars = 0;
```

Any of the above will return:
[no PHP notice]
TRUE

```
$vars = "anything";
```

will return:
FALSE

This is because with the exclamation mark you are testing if the var is FALSE, so when not initialised with a string the test script returns TRUE because it is NOT FALSE.

When we initialise it with a string then the var NOT being FALSE is FALSE.

**`empty($vars)`**

Example code:

```
if ( empty($vars) )
 {
  echo "TRUE";
 }
else
 {
  echo "FALSE";
}
```

Not initialised/set at all, and all of the following:

```
$vars = "";
$vars = NULL;
$vars = 0;
```

will return:
TRUE

There is no PHP notice for using empty, so here we show a difference between the two options (and remember when I said the shortest code is not necessarily the "best"? Depends on the scenario etc.).

And as with the previous test:

```
$vars = "anything";
```

returns:
FALSE

This is the same with `( !$var )`, you are testing IF EMPTY, and without the var being initialised at all, or with any "`empty()`" value: eg (""), or NULL, or zero (0), then testing if the var is empty is TRUE, so we get TRUE output.

You get FALSE when setting the var to a string because IS EMPTY = FALSE as we set it to something.

---

The difference is `empty()` does not throw a PHP notice when var is not defined, whereas `(!$var)` will.

Also, you may prefer it for being "shorter code", but `if (!$var)` isn't really much shorter/better looking than the widely used `if (empty($var))`.

But again, this depends on the scenario - PHP provides different options to suit different requirements.

Comment: you have add a long answer, some of you assumption or "advices" are obviosly, no need to say how to write code. something like this will be clear: empty($var) === !$var and empty will not raise and warning on undefined variables.

Answer (score 4):

No they are not equal

```
if(empty($var)){
  echo "empty used\n";
}


if(!$var){ # line no. 6
  echo "! used";
}
```

will output

```
empty used
Notice: Undefined variable: var in /var/www/html/test.php on line 6
! used
```

Following values are considered to be empty when using empty() function

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

As you can read in [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) docs

> empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var
>   == false.

Comment: Also as addition if a variable is not set `empty` is true but `!$var` is a undefined variable!

Comment: You’re using `$vars` and not `$var` in your second test.

Comment: if `$var ="0"` empty will return true, but `!isset($var) || $var == false ` will return false?`

Answer (score 3):

They are not.
The first one verify if $var has any value.
The second one verify as boolean - if true or not.

The second one will give you a notice, the first one will be true if the value is empty for $var.

If you wish to verify if $var exists, use isset.

```
if( !isset($var) )
    echo '$var does not exists!<br>';

if(empty($var))
    echo 'The value is empty or does not exists!<br>';

if( !$var )
    echo 'Value is false!<br>';

$var = '';
if(empty($var))
    echo 'The value is empty or does not exists!<br>';
```

Use this to view the notice

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that empty() will not complain if the variable does not exist, whereas using ! will generate a warning.

In older versions of PHP, empty() only worked on direct variables, meaning this would fail:

```
empty($a && $b);
```

This has been changed in 5.5

Comment: This does not give an answer to the question.

Comment: @fdomig: way better than yours.

Answer (score 1):

The official manual contains all you have to know on this subject:

http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

`if (!$var)` is the last column, `boolean : if($x)` *negated*.

As you can see they are the same, *but* `empty` won't complain if the variable wasn't set.

From the manual:

```
empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist
```

Take some time, and study that chart.

Comment: that chart shows that empty and !$var are totally equivalent from a boolean value return

Comment: they are equivalent. though I'm not sure what you meant by "from a boolean value return". this page also shows the difference, "Note:
Simply doing if ($x) while $x is undefined will generate an error of level E_NOTICE. Instead, consider using empty() or isset() and/or initialize your variables.". it's all in the documentation.

Comment: I mean that I do not care about the notice, I care more about $ret = !$vars. anyway $vars="0" as string disappoints me that empty return true, it is a string with length 1!!

Comment: PHP is just a big pile of horrible designs... that's why these pages are so valuable. you should *never* test string emptyness with `empty`. and you really *should* care about notices, ignoring them is bad practice (if you meant it's not relevant to your specific problem then I understand that - but this is not clear from the context).

Comment: yes , normally of course I care about notice, I mean in the context here.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's pretty simple.

`empty()` is basically equivalent to `!isset($var) || !$var` and does not throw any warnings/notices, whereas using just `!$var` will throw a notice if the variable isn't defined.

[image: code and log]
[image: output]

For the sake of completeness, the following are considered empty when using `empty()`:

1. empty strings
2. empty arrays
3. `0`, `0.0`, `'0'` (int, float, string)
4. `null`
5. `false`
6. defined variables without a value

Comment: so the only difference is the fact that the empty will not throw a notice, but they return the same boolean value right?

Comment: `if (empty($var)) echo 'empty'; if (!$var) echo 'empty';` will indeed execute `echo 'empty';` twice.

Comment: To dig a little into the internals, if anything in a OR statement returns true, the rest won't be checked. In `empty()`, if `$var` isn't defined, `!isset($var)` will return `true` and thus already break the statement. If you only do `!$var` it can't check the var because it's not defined.